# What is the Javascript event for an item being added to the cart in Woocommerce?

Tags: javascript, plugins, events

I can't seem to find this in the docs or through google. So basically I'm just looking for the Javascript event that fires when an item is added to the cart. <strike>For some reason my default added to cart notification isn't working.</strike>

EDIT:
So I'm thinking because I'm including the woocommerce.php file in my themes default folder as well as my woocommerce template overrides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the source.  From woocommerce-ajax.php (in the plugin's root folder)

**Javascript/Ajax add to cart**

```
/**
 * AJAX add to cart
 *
 * @access public
 * @return void
 */
function woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart() {

    global $woocommerce;

    check_ajax_referer( 'add-to-cart', 'security' );

    $product_id = (int) apply_filters('woocommerce_add_to_cart_product_id', $_POST['product_id']);

    $passed_validation = apply_filters('woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', true, $product_id, 1);

    if ($passed_validation && $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart($product_id, 1)) :
        // Return html fragments
        $data = apply_filters('add_to_cart_fragments', array());
        do_action( 'woocommerce_ajax_added_to_cart', $product_id);
    else :
        // If there was an error adding to the cart, redirect to the product page to show any errors
        $data = array(
            'error' => true,
            'product_url' => get_permalink( $product_id )
        );
        $woocommerce->set_messages();
    endif;

    echo json_encode( $data );

    die();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart');
```

**Non-AJAX: Requires Page Load**

If you are not using AJAX then you are using the `woocommerce_add_to_cart_action()` from woocommerce-functions.php which runs on the `init` hook.  It is a bit long, so I will just let you read it from the mentioned file.   Basically it looks for an add-to-cart` query parameter (which should equal the product ID) and goes from there.

Comment: Is this the default template used? What if say I'm not using AJAX and the page reloads to add an item to the cart?

Comment: You asked for the javascript event/action. The non-ajax add to cart is handled by the `woocommerce_add_to_cart_action()` function which fires on the `init` hook.

Comment: @helgatheviking I used the following code in my template file
$_REQUEST['add-to-cart'] = $proid;
$_REQUEST['quantity'] = $qty;
global $woocommerce;
woocommerce_add_to_cart_action(); to add the products in to the cart. But it not working. what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: You should really ask your own question.  And when you do try to be really specific about what you are doing and where you are failing.  "it is not working" doesn't tell anyone anything useful.